# Log Parser - How to query the log in multiple folders?

Tags: logparser

Log files are available inside the 1500 folders.

```
D:\temp\output\BG Output_Last_0001\log.txt
D:\temp\output\BG Output_Last_0002\log.txt
D:\temp\output\BG Output_Last_0003\log.txt
D:\temp\output\BG Output_Last_0004\log.txt
D:\temp\output\BG Output_Last_0005\log.txt
.
.
```

I can get the output of parsing a single log file using the below command.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2>LogParser -i:TSV "select MIN(Datetime) AS StartTime from 'D:\temp\output\log_0001\log.txt'" -o:datagrid
```

**What I tried:**

I tried the below command to parse using the * symbol in Log Parser

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2>LogParser -i:TSV "select MIN(Datetime) AS StartTime from 'D:\temp\output\*\log.txt'" -o:datagrid

D:\temp\output\*\log.txt
```

Can someone help how to parse the log from the multiple folders?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PowerShell script

Conceptual script, I didn't try it out:

```
$IISLogPath = 'D:\temp\output\'
$logPaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $IISLogPath  -Recurse 
$logPaths = "$($logPaths -join ",")"  <-- join multiple files into one-liner

$logParserPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe"
$query = 
@"
SELECT select MIN(TO_LOCALTIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(date, time)))
FROM '$logPaths'
"@

& $logParserPath -i:IISW3C $query -stats:OFF -rtp:-1
}
```